# Android Virtual Devices not visible to Flutter or Visual Studio Code (but OK in Android Studio)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

There are many similar questions out there, but none of them help (for instance, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045393/flutter-run-no-connected-devices) is well upvoted, with a well upvoted answer, and would seem to be a dupe. ***BUT*** like others who commented there, the answer did not help me (also, the answer is 2 years old, which is an eternity on Flutter)).

At most, they tell how to add an Android VM in Android Studio. I have done so:
[image]

They also suggest setting the environment variables `ANDROID_HOME` and/or `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`. I have set both to the same value:

```
C:\Users\me>dir %ANDROID_HOME%
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is FE0C-16F0

 Directory of C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

17/06/2020  12:18    <DIR>          .
17/06/2020  12:18    <DIR>          ..
19/06/2020  10:46    <DIR>          .downloadIntermediates
20/06/2020  07:22                16 .knownPackages
19/06/2020  10:47    <DIR>          .temp
14/06/2020  13:15    <DIR>          build-tools
17/06/2020  12:18    <DIR>          cmdline-tools
08/06/2020  13:53    <DIR>          emulator
08/06/2020  18:35    <DIR>          extras
16/06/2020  12:50    <DIR>          licenses
08/06/2020  13:53    <DIR>          patcher
19/06/2020  10:47    <DIR>          platform-tools
08/06/2020  19:21    <DIR>          platforms
16/06/2020  12:59    <DIR>          skins
08/06/2020  13:55    <DIR>          sources
14/06/2020  13:15    <DIR>          system-images
08/06/2020  13:54    <DIR>          tools
               1 File(s)             16 bytes
              16 Dir(s)  18,697,719,808 bytes free

C:\Users\me>
```

When I create the default Flutter app, Android Studio shows me the VMs as an option for run/debug:

[image]

***BUT***, when I open that same project's folder (or any other) with Visual Studio Code and run, it launches in the Chrome browser, because:

```
PS C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app> flutter devices
3 connected devices:

Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 83.0.4103.106
Edge       • edge       • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 83.0.478.54
PS C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app>
```

**How do get Flutter to recognize my Android virtual machines?**

**I can see that each has a sub-directory in `c:\Users\me\.android\avd`. How do I make Flutter aware of it?**

Here's the output of Flutter doctor, for completeness:

```
C:\Users\me>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.20.0-1.0.pre.132, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.20.0-1.0.pre.132 at e:\coding\flutter
    • Framework revision 5995661777 (8 hours ago), 2020-06-19 16:15:58 -0700
    • Engine revision 676cd566f7
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-17.0.dev 7e72c9ae7e)


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-R, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Java binary at: E:\coding\Android_studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at E:\coding\Android_studio
    • Flutter plugin version 46.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 83.0.4103.106
    • Edge       • edge       • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 83.0.478.54

• No issues found!

C:\Users\me>
```

This is interesting: when I run a Flutter app in Android Studio, its VM suddenly becomes visible in Flutter/Visual Studio Code:

PS C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app> flutter devices
***4*** connected devices:

> ***sdk gphone x86 arm • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API
> 30) (emulator) Web Server         • web-server    • web-javascript •***
> Flutter Tools Chrome             • chrome        • web-javascript •
> Google Chrome 83.0.4103.106 Edge               • edge          •
> web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 83.0.478.54 PS
> C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app>

When I stop the  device in Android Studio, Flutter can no longer see it.

Answer (score 1):

I *highly* suggest that you use Git to install Flutter, then install the Android SDK with Android Studio. Don't forget to add Flutter/bin to your PATH. Then create your Virtual Device in Android Studio and it should show up in Visual Studio Code and the console.

Answer (score 1):

Run your virtual device in AVD manager
Then while it is running go to your flutter.console terminal
Try flutter doctor in terminal see if the device show in the list

To see Devices: show devices in terminal

if device is visible navigate to your flutter project.

in my case:  C:\Users\husmi\StudioProjects\testapp

and in terminal type 'flutter run'

It worked for me!!

flutter console
[image: 1]

command in flutter console
[image: 2]

Try this site.

https://flutteragency.com/solve-no-connected-devices-in-flutter/